# Cross compiling arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi with Crosstool

Tags: c, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I've got a problem with cross compiling GCC to `arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi`. (My real target is android but this one produces output that runs on my phone)

I successfully created a normal cross compiler but I want to create a compiler that runs on my target. I assumed I would do something like that: `build=x86_64-linux-gnu host=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi` with Canadian Cross. But somehow it fails even if I hadn't changed anything on my `.config` file and creating the new compiler after compiling the "normal" one. I want the compiler to be statically linked could it be something with that?
So could someone send me a configuration of successful build or give me a compiler that works on it?